# Having difficulties understanding Python's logger propagation

Tags: python, logging

In the `logging.json` file defining the configuration of my loggers I defined a logger `script_logger` with a handler `console` set to output every logging messages to stdout. It has `"propagate": "no"` because I do not want the event to be propagated to the root logger, but when I create a logging message, it is shown twice on the stdout anyway.

The only way to not have the message twice is to remove the handler `console` from the `root` logger. The `propagate` attribute seems to have no effect.

Why? Anybody can help?

```
$ python test_script.py
2015-09-02 14:26:35,436 - script_logger - DEBUG - debug msg
2015-09-02 14:26:35,436 - script_logger - DEBUG - debug msg
```

**test_script.py**

```
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logger = logging.getLogger("script_logger")
    logger.debug("debug msg")
```

**logging.json**

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        }, 

        "info_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "info.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,                                                                      
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },

        "error_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",                                           
            "level": "ERROR",                                                                          
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "errors.log",                                                                  
            "maxBytes": 10485760,                                                                      
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"                                                                         
        }                                                                                              
    },                                                                                                 

    "loggers": {
        "script_logger": {
            "level": "DEBUG",                                                                          
            "handlers": ["console"],                                                                   
            "propagate": "no"
        }
    },                                                                                                 

    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["console", "info_file_handler", "error_file_handler"]                             
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is logged twice because the `console` logger is in both the `root` and the `script_logger` -- But I think you already know that.

Just replace `"propagate": "no"` with `"propagate": False` and everything will work as you intended.

Comment: That "no" looked strange indeed. I copied that example from the only json example I found (http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python) and trusted it too much! Thanks.